# How to complete function to use pointer arithmetic instead of array subscripting in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am struggling with specific parts in my code that I seem to have formatted wrong. This code was taken from my programming book and the parts that were blank have a '$' around them. However, there are two blanks I can't seem to figure out. My current code is:

```
int sum_two_dimensional(const int a[][LEN], int n)
{
  int i,j, sum = 0;
  for(i=0, i<n; i++)
     for(j = 0; j< LEN; j++)
       sum+=a[i][j];
  return sum;
}

int sum_two_dimensional_array(const in a[][LEN], int n)
{
  int *p, sum = 0;

  for(p= a[0]; p < a[0] ______; p++)
      sum += ________;                     //my guess is a[p][sum];
  return sum;
}
```

I tried several things in these blanks an it seems that I keep getting errors. I do not fully understand the array/pointer situation. The blanks that I filled in, (encased in $$$), I feel are right but feel free to double check me. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be really useful to know which book it is.

Comment: @Troy C programming, a modern approach. Version 2

Comment: what is `in` ? ...

Comment: The title says you want to rewrite a function, but the question suggests you want to know what to put in the blanks. Which is it?

Comment: 1) `for(j = 0; j< LEN; j++)`, 2) `for(p=&a[0][0];p<&a[n-1][LEN];p++)`, `sum+=*p;`

Comment: @M.M I fixed typo, and I want to know at least a hint or approach of what to fill in

Comment: As in [C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Modern-Approach-2nd/dp/0393979504) by K N King?  It's a decent book, AFAICR.

Comment: What is the problem you get with the first one, `$$$LEN$$$`?  What is `LEN` defined as?  It looks like it should be fine unless `LEN` is defined as something particularly outré.

Comment: the last 2 blanks would be `+ n*LEN` and `*p` .

Comment: @JohnathanLeffler I get no problem. I just filled that part in and I am pretty sure it was right but put it in '$' if anyone else had other suggestions. I am more worried about the blanks

Comment: @M.M thank you, could you explain why and/or your reasoning?

Comment: I think it'd be less confusing if you take out the `$$$$$$` and just show the code as it appears in the book with all the blanks,  and then explain which bits you filled in which blanks

Comment: @CodeFreak you first need to understand using a pointer to iterate over a 1-D array. I'd suggest reading material on that first. Once you understand that then this will be a small step on top of that. (`*p` is the same in both cases, it is just specifying the end condition that is slightly different for the 2-D array)

Answer (score 1):

This exploits the fact that an array `a[N][M]` uses the same memory as a single dimension array `a[N*M]`

So you can "safely" iterate `a[0]` "out of bound" without triggering memory exception up to the index `a[0][N*M-1]`

```
int sum_two_dimensional_array( int a[][LEN], int n)
{
  int *p, sum = 0;

  for(p= a[0]; p < a[0]+n*LEN; p++)
      sum += *p;
  return sum;
}
```